# Adding a texture map to a beveled curve or path

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves

I really want to be able to apply mapping to a curve object. For instance a rope or pipe that has a repeated pattern along its length that follows it's twists and turns.

There must be a simple way to generate UV coordinates for such an object without converting it to a mesh and unwrapping it. Can anyone help?

Comment: http://johnnygizmo.blogspot.nl/2014/06/striping-curve-in-blendercycles.html has some good tips on UV mapping on a beveled curve.

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can. Just simply toggle the **Use UV for mapping** option in **Properties** Editor > **Object Data** Tab > **Texture space** panel.

[image]

### For **BI** render

- In order to use UV coordinate, you have to convert the curve object into a mesh object to store UV (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > <kbd>2</kbd>). Just besure to have that optio toggled, which will automatically generate a neat UV (named **Orco** by default). and set Texture coornidate to UV:

[image]

- If you don't want to convert the curve object into a mesh, for regular use, you have a nice option, by using **Generated** coodinate instead for texture:

[image]

### For **Cycles** Render:

- After toggling **Use UV for mapping** option, you can immidiately see the automatic Orco UV in 3D View, Cycles will by default use UV coordinate for both curve and mesh:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and quickest way to create UV for a pipe (curve) without having to convert it to a mesh is to use the generated UVs.

1. I am assuming that you are using cycles
2. Assign a (diffuse) material to your mesh (in the materials tab) if you haven't already

   [image]
3. Add an image to your material, Shift + A -> Texture -> Image Texture
4. Add an UV input, Shift + A -> Input -> Texture Coordinate

   [image]

NOTE:

- the curve is still intact, you don't have to convert to mesh
- the generated UV is not perfect and there may be some minor stretching

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This answer only applies if you are using cycles to render your scene. Note that I can't provide an answer for the internal renderer.

However, in cycles, this can be achieved easily by using the following note setup. This generates a nicely distributed trexture ove the beveled curve (I guess that is what you want):

[image: Texture and node setup]