# Apply Texture map to 2D curve from svg

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves

I'm trying to map an image onto a shape(svg) that is the same as shape/size as the image.  I'm trying to do a digital version of decoupage cards. I cut out each shape as a layer. I export the base shape for the layer as an SVG from Inkscape. I then export that layer's color data as an image.

After getting stumped I attempted to follow this: [SO texture mapping question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/adding-a-texture-map-to-a-beveled-curve-or-path) to no avail though.

In Blender v2.7.6, I blow away the default cube. Import the .svg. Click on the svg, in the Properties->Curve->Texture Space I tick 'Use UV Mapping'.
I then go to Properties->Texture->Image load up the image ->Mapping I set Coordinates -> Generated. And this is what I get-> [image: And this is what I get]

If I try the other method and extrude the path and then turn that into a mesh, switch to the Compositing view, I get this:
[image: Weird UV Mapping]
I'm unable to move the mesh around or do anything. I'm a bit stumped at this point.  I followed this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUkNOF8eORA) for that method

I can easily get the texture map to appear on a cube or plane but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this situation.

Sample files per request: image map->[image: image map]
svg->[SVGfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hra29a0h43cxx91/Untitled.svg?dl=0)

Comment: Can you upload the image and the svg in question? It would be helpful help too to add an image that shows what you are after (I'm not sure what you mean with decoupage card).

Comment: This is the effect I'm going for: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_h2qJID3nDAI/TMgBGlOXHCI/AAAAAAAAFB0/4ptl4i-9yiI/s1600/23102010753.jpg basically it is making a 2D scene 3D by making layers using various pieces of an image.  Kinda like making a homegrown depth map and applying it to certain pieces. Hmmm  maybe that's how I should go about things...a depth map/bump map/ height map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Match Texture space on the curve.

Then set your coordinates to Object.

You need then to adjust size and offset a bit.

[image]

Comment: Is there a trick to setting the size and offset? I'm basically just changing the offset and size and watching the placement in the 3D view with Viewport Shading set to Rendered. It is a bit time consuming and if I have X pieces in a piece I think this might be a bit too time consuming. Is there a trick or do you just get a feel after doing a couple?  Also Do you have to readjust each time you move the camera? I noticed that when I moved the camera around I had to re-maneuver things to get the texture to line up again :(.

Comment: My feeling is that for what you are after you'd be better off with a simple plane. In the image editing program you prefer just erase the white space and make it transparent, then import that using the images as planes addon makin sure that you use the alpha channel as transparency. Then use a texture as image bump or displacement.