# How to make a generated texture follow a Bezier curve?

Tags: texturing, bezier-curves

I'm animating a representation of fluid flow by using a generated Wave texture, animating the mapping to make the rings travel. This works well for a cylindrical object; but for a bent tube, the rings get distorted, as I'm (simplistically) animating along the object's y value (which works fine for the cylinder).

Here's the textured tube and the material nodes:
[image: Textured tube and the material nodes]

The tube is a Bezier curve with a circle used as a bevel object. I can convert to a mesh if need be, but I'd prefer not to.

Is there a mapping that would cause the texture to propagate along the Bezier, with one animatable parameter that will cause the rings to travel along the tube?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/adding-a-texture-map-to-a-beveled-curve-or-path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the pointer, Carlo. Yes, enabling "use UV for mapping" helped; but I also needed to change from Object to UV as the input to the mapping node:
[image: Textured hose now looks right]

Animating the Y parameter of the mapping node makes the rings travel along the tube as desired. Thanks!