# Creating text on paper?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

Edit: This is not a duplicate of [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles) because that question only seems to talk about adding an image texture, not combining an image texture with additional shader effects.

Original question:

I want to make the paper you'd find in a fortune cookie. To create the shape, I extruded a bezier curve and added a Solidify modifier to it.

For the material, I tried this:

- Made an image texture and added text in Photoshop
- Made a Principled BSDF shader with subsurface scattering
- Used an Add Shader to combine the other two shaders

However, the text of the image gets faded:

[image: Fortune says: Today is the first day of the rest of your life.]

How would I put opaque text on translucent paper?

Comment: Hello :). Here is a good way to do it: https://imgur.com/gzaPHng You need to have one material for your Ink, another (translucent) one for your paper. Then just use your black&white text image to drive the visibility.

Comment: You also need to UV unwrap your paper, for this to work properly, as suggested in the linked (duplicate) question) :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Wow, I would not have thought of that solution! Is there a way to accomplish my goal without UV unwrapping? I like having my paper as a bezier curve, so I don't want to convert it to a mesh. Thank you! :)

Comment: Of course there is a way :). https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9322/78972

Comment: Turns out I didn't even need the Generated mapping. I thought I did, because I was having trouble with your suggested node layout, but once I made sure my PNG was pure black and white (no grays), your solution totally worked. Thank you so much, @JachymMichal! :)

Comment: Happy to help. It was a nice coincidence - I needed this exact thing just a two days ago, so I'm glad it benefited someone else :). Perhaps next time I'll learn new stuff from you. Have a nice day.