# Cant apply texture to object because it is missing UV coordinates

Tags: uv

I have this simulation of rope (made with gravity rope).
when I try to apply complex texture to it via Keyshot- I get the error that the texture can not be applied because there are no UV Coordinates.

It seems like the deformable meshes that are exported are exported without UV coordinates- even though UV is selected when exporting

any advise on how to export the Alembic file with UV coordinates is much appreciated.
here is a link to the file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/r4o7buvql748ps0/rope%20test%205.blend?dl=0

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Since Blender 2.8, curves have a UV map all the time.

If using versions before 2.80, as mentioned in [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9322/53447), you need to enable the `Use UV for mapping` option in Properties Editor > Object Data Tab > Texture space panel:

[image: UV Map Option]

Alembic export with UVs enabled in export options should work just fine.

I wasn't able to test on your scene since the curve object was empty. But theoretically it should work.