# Why do these curves look see-through?

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

I'm trying to create hair for my character. I used curves, which I didn't want to use but every time I use hair particles Blender shuts down on me, and I created a hair texture for it. It seemed perfect but when I entered render view, I noticed that you can still see the scalp through the curves. How do I fix this problem? Do I have to convert them to meshes or is there something I'm missing here? I'm using Blender 2.93 and it doesn't seem to have the "Use For UV Mapping" option like in here: [Adding a texture map to a beveled curve or path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9319/adding-a-texture-map-to-a-beveled-curve-or-path) in case anyone asks.

Also, what does the Path Tracing Sample line mean?

If it helps, I included a screenshot of the material I created.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's see-through because you're mixing your Principled with a Transparent BSDF.  If you don't want it see-through, don't do that.  There is no longer any need to enable "use for UV mapping"; all curves create UV maps that can be used from texture coordinate nodes.  "Path tracing Sample 10/32" on your stats means that your rendered preview is trying to render 32 samples per pixel, and it has so far rendered 10 of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seams like you have 2 main problems with the material. 1. The gradient texture moves transparent part too far from the scalp (guessing that it's curves beginning). Move it a little. 2. Too wide transparent streaks. Try to tight them up by moving points on the color ramp that controls that aspect closer to black (cause your mix shader that mixes transparent with the rest shows more transparent when the value is closer to 1 and less of it if it's closer to 0 because of input placement - transparent shader lower the rest higher). Hope it helps.

Comment: Both of these comments were very helpful. Thanks!